# Cryptic error when attempting the collect() function on a remote database in R

Tags: r, dplyr, odbc, dbplyr, rjdbc

I am trying to run the code below and I got the error at the bottom:

```
prg3 <- 
+   prg2 %>% 
+   select(PGPRDC,
+          PGAGRP,
+          PGCAT1,
+          PGCAT2,
+          PGCAT3,
+          PGCAT4,
+          PGCDAT,
+          PGRFDT,
+          PGRTDT,
+          PGSUPP,
+          PGSHNO,
+          PGDESC,
+          PGSUPC,
+          PGRESP,
+          PGAPCO,
+          PGA6CO, #second avg cost?
+          PGASCO,
+          PGBCOS,
+          PGFCOS,
+          PGHNDV,
+          PGMULT,
+          PGBGAP,
+          everything()) %>% 
+   rename(prod_code = PGPRDC,
+          prod_acct_grp = PGAGRP,
+          cat1 = PGCAT1,
+          cat2 = PGCAT2,
+          cat3 = PGCAT3,
+          cat4 = PGCAT4,
+          prod_creation_date = PGCDAT,
+          prod_replace_from_date = PGRFDT,
+          prod_replace_to_date = PGRTDT,
+          supplier_number = PGSUPP,
+          prod_short_name = PGSHNO,
+          prod_desc = PGDESC,
+          supercede_yn = PGSUPC,
+          responible = PGRESP,
+          unit = PGUNIT,
+          vehicle_make = PGPGRP,
+          lot = PGBATC,
+          lead_time = PGLEAD,
+          structure_code = PGSTRC,
+          override_price_yn = PGOVDC,
+          backlog_code_yn = PGBALC,
+          avg_purch_cost = PGAPCO,
+          standard_cost = PGASCO,
+          base_cost = PGBCOS,
+          future_cost = PGFCOS,
+          handling_cost = PGHNDV,
+          prod_weight = PGWEIG,
+          car_line_ABC = PGABCC,
+          car_line_popularity = PGROPC,
+          company_wide_ABC = PGEOQC,
+          image_crit_core = PGSECT,
+          con_ctr_init_qty = PGPQTY,
+          pack_size = PGSIZE,
+          selling_increment = PGSINC,
+          avg_purch_cost2 = PGA6CO,
+          base_cost_multiplier = PGMULT,
+          avg_and_base_cost_gap = PGBGAP,
+          country_code = PGCOUN) %>%  collect()

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Timer-0"
Error in ._jobjRef_dollar(x[["jobj"]], name) : 
  no field, method or inner class called 'use_cli_format'
```

The PRG_ objects are remote connections to a DB2 database with the following connection parameters:

```
driver <- JDBC("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver", 
               "C:/Program Files/ibm/IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER/java/db2jcc4.jar")
               
password
conn <- dbConnect(driver, 
                  "jdbc:db2://wwtc.worldpac.com/S1013FCD", 
                  "username", 
                  "pw")

prg = tbl(conn, in_schema("ASDFLIB01", "SROPRG"))
```

I can us `dplyr` verbs to filter and such, but as soon as I collect() it throws that error.

I have
R version 4.2.2
tidyverse 1.3.2
RJDBC 0.2-10
dbplyr 2.3.0

I have restarted my R session multiple times and I have updated the java version on my local machine. I am not sure how to proceed next?

Comment: The OutOfMemoryError makes it sound like you simply do not have enough RAM to collect all the records you are requesting. Do you know how many records you are expecting?

Comment: I am expecting approximately 100 million rows to be returned.  I tried with a smaller dataset as well and the errors were the same

Comment: How much smaller exactly? It's not clear what's in all these columns so I'm not sure how much memory I would expect these rows to take up. But once you call `collect()` all the data from the query is loaded into memory. And if your machine doesn't have the resources for that, there's not a lot you can do.